# gc log is minor gc or full gc

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

Here is the jvm gc log for my demo application:

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=44040192 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:InitialHeapSize=10485760 -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=134217728 -XX:MaxHeapSize=10485760 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=52428800 -XX:MaxNewSize=5242880 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=6 -XX:MetaspaceSize=52428800 -XX:NewSize=5242880 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseParNewGC 
2019-12-03T21:43:04.462-0800: 0.279: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-12-03T21:43:04.462-0800: 0.279: [ParNew: 4048K->512K(4608K), 0.0020396 secs] 4048K->722K(9728K), 0.0021283 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-12-03T21:43:04.469-0800: 0.286: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-12-03T21:43:04.469-0800: 0.286: [ParNew: 4608K->418K(4608K), 0.0022851 secs] 4818K->3190K(9728K), 0.0023372 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-12-03T21:43:04.475-0800: 0.291: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-12-03T21:43:04.475-0800: 0.291: [ParNew: 4514K->4514K(4608K), 0.0000198 secs]2019-12-03T21:43:04.475-0800: 0.291: [CMS: 2771K->2764K(5120K), 0.0040364 secs] 7286K->2764K(9728K), [Metaspace: 4253K->4253K(1056768K)], 0.0041089 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-12-03T21:43:04.481-0800: 0.297: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-12-03T21:43:04.481-0800: 0.297: [ParNew: 4096K->4096K(4608K), 0.0000200 secs]2019-12-03T21:43:04.481-0800: 0.297: [CMS: 2764K->2721K(5120K), 0.0031319 secs] 6860K->2721K(9728K), [Metaspace: 4253K->4253K(1056768K)], 0.0032046 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

Everything is expected, except the line 4 and line 5. As its title is GC(Allocation Failure), it seems a minor gc caused by allocation failure at eden space. However, the log details contains the CMS and Metaspace infos, which makes it like a Full GC.

So could anyone tell line 4 and line 5 are Minor GC(young gc) or Full GC(young+tenured+metaspace)?

If they're minor gc, what's the difference between line 2, 3 and line 4,5?

If they're full gc, what cause the full gc?

Comment: are you sure you copy/pasted correct logs? Even the first line looks weird : `2019-12-03T21:43:04.462-0800: 0.279: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-12...`

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I am sure. I have checked the logs again, and it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say definitively from what you've posted but here are more details of how the GC works.

With CMS, the idea is to avoid a full GC.  A full GC for CMS occurs when occupancy and fragmentation are too high to enable the VM to easily allocate space for new objects in the old gen.  At this point, the VM will pause all application threads and do a full compacting collection to eliminate all fragmentation by moving objects to be contiguous in memory.  That is not what you are seeing here.

CMS is mostly-concurrent, i.e. certain phases of the collection (concurrent marking, precleaning, sweeping and reset) can happen while application threads are running.  The initial marking phase is stop-the-world and is often triggered by a minor GC so occurs directly after the minor GC.  This may be what you are observing here so lines 4 and 5 are recording the two events together (minor GC and triggering of CMS initial marking phase).

Comment: if that would be case, I would expect a line containing `CMS Initial Mark...`, which is not present.